# Layer of StarSan on beer

Tags: sanitizer, starsan

So during a cold crash I sucked around a quart of StarSan onto my beer, there's a layer ~1/2 inch thick sitting on top of the beer. Should I try to siphon off this top layer, or wait until i get a keg (a week or two) and just rack whats underneath it?

Comment: Related (also read the answer - properly prepared StarSan is actually safe to drink): http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6599/sanitizer-sucked-back-into-beer-dangerous

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry too much about it. As @valverij said, StarSan is safe to drink at this concentration. I would try to siphon most of it off, especially if you need to move the beer before kegging. Moving it will likely mix the beer with the sanitizer.

StarSan in water is almost without any smell or taste, so I don't think it will affect your beer much even if you leave it in.

Comment: You can't siphon it off, you have to take the beer out from under it. Starsan will add a sour acidic taste and mouthfeel to a beer. 1tsp in a 12oz beer simulates this well in a doctored beer

Answer (score 1):

No worries, BUT: take your beer out of cold conditioning and let it warm up to diecetyl rest temperature. You will see some action in your airlock as the yeast consume the chemicals that are in star san. Wait until activity has finished and then cold crash again with out adding more star san! :P

I recommend using a bubbler when cold crashing as the liquid will not be sucked into your beer. Otherwise, put a loose knot in your blow-off tube, this can create the same effect as a bubbler.

Comment: This usually happens after Diacetyl rest and lagering to quickly, or temp control fail.  Bubblers will most defenatly bell syphon, but suck in a small quantity.

Comment: Yeast will not consume the "chemicals"  in starsan.

Comment: Making a peetrap with a knot in the blow off tube only works if the tube has a diameter large enough to break the fluid tension and the end is not sumberged, or it will still syphon. Basic hydro dynamics.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers, don't worry too much. You don't want it in your beer though, it will add a sour hint of acid.

It would seem you could siphon off the top but you cant, it mixes too easily. Trick is to rack the beer "out" of the trub on the bottom and the starsan on top.

Next time do slow temp drops 1° an hour. Idea is to allow co2 production to compensate for gas shrinkage.  Or cap the fermentor with a starter sponge or foil.